# TeX Live 2020 - tlmgr cannot load perl-tk although it is installed

Tags: packages, texlive, tlmgr, perl, texlive-2020

I installed TeX Live 2020 on my Linux system. When I try to invoke `tlmgr --gui` I get the error message

```
tlmgr: Cannot load Tk, thus the GUI cannot be started!
The Perl/Tk module is not shipped with the TeX Live installation.
You have to install it to get the tlmgr GUI working.
(INC = /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive /usr/local/texlive/2020/tlpkg /home/robert/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/robert/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /home/robert/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/robert/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2 .)

See https://tug.org/texlive/distro.html#perltk for more details.
Goodbye.
```

However, I do have perl-tk installed. `sudo apt-get install perl-tk` returns `... perl-tk is already the newest version (1:804.033-2build1).`

With TeX Live 2019, which I had installed previously on the same system, this problem did not occur.
Any idea how I could get `tlmgr --gui` to work?

Comment: I just tried to do this by installing Perl with Anaconda, and that worked. I then installed perl-tk with Anaconda but when I tried running `tlmgr --gui` I got an error about some `X11` library(ies) missing. I gave up and removed Perl and perl-tk. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. The `tug.org` website seems to be down at them moment too.

Comment: As a quick test of Perl/Tk, does '/usr/bin/widget' work?

Comment: Yes, ```/usr/bin/widget``` works.

Comment: I saw in the error message a reference of a perl installation under /home/robert/anaconda3/ . This does not look like a debian/ubuntu perl installation. So you might try to move this installation out of the way, so that tlmgr tries to use the distribution perl.

Comment: Removing ```/home/robert/anaconda3/bin``` from the ```PATH``` variable indeed solved the problem. Thanks for the hint. If you want to turn your comment into an answer I am happy to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, Robert, I missed your answer before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a competing perl without perl/tk on your system make sure the distribution package comes first on your PATH.